# eNewsletter email application is not sending emails

Tags: php, email, smtp

so heres my function that gets called when I send out a email blast using an internal php application that was developed for one of our clients by a programmer who hasnt worked here in years.

Its saying that "X Emails were sent successfully!", But I never receive them. :/

Maybe I need to be more specific with logging errors, because I cant find what is causing it.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
function SendBroadCastEmail() {

ini_set("SMTP", "206.196.112.2" ); 
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'theagencykc@gmail.com'); 


$clsPortfolio = new Portfolio();
if ($_REQUEST["frmBroadcastGroup"] == "All") {
    $strWhere = "";
}elseif ($_REQUEST["frmBroadcastGroup"] == "Active") {
    $strWhere = " WHERE p.Active = 1 ";
}elseif ($_REQUEST["frmBroadcastGroup"] == "Custom") {
    $selectEmails = array_unique($_REQUEST['frmBroadcastRecipentList']);
    $strWhere = " WHERE ";
    foreach ($selectEmails as $intRecipent) {
        $strWhere .= " OR Portfolio_ID = '$intRecipent' ";
    }
    $strWhere = str_replace(" WHERE  OR", " WHERE ", $strWhere);
}
$clsPortfolio->GetList($strWhere);
if ($rsRecipients = mysql_fetch_array($clsPortfolio->rsResult)) {
    do {
        if (trim($rsRecipients["Email"]) == "") {
            $aryNoEmail[] = array("Name" => stripslashes($rsRecipients["Name"]), "Portfolio_ID" => $rsRecipients["Portfolio_ID"]) ;
        }else{
            $aryRecipents[] = $rsRecipients["Email"];
        }
    } while($rsRecipients = mysql_fetch_array($clsPortfolio->rsResult));
}

$strHeaders  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$strHeaders .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$strHeaders .= "From: theagencykc@gmail.com\r\n";
foreach ($aryRecipents as $strRecipient) {
    mail(stripslashes($strRecipient), stripslashes($_REQUEST["frmBroadcastSubject"]),stripslashes( $_REQUEST["frmBroadcastBody"]), $strHeaders);
    if (mail(stripslashes($strRecipient), stripslashes($_REQUEST["frmBroadcastSubject"]),stripslashes( $_REQUEST["frmBroadcastBody"]), $strHeaders)) {
       echo("<p>Message successfully sent, buddy!</p>");
    } else {
       echo("<p>Message delivery failed... buddy</p>");
    }
}
$strBroadcastResults = "<b>" . count($aryRecipents) . " Emails Sent Successfully<br>";
if (count($aryNoEmail) > 0) {
    $strBroadcastResults .= "<u>The following models had no email on file:</u><br>";
    foreach ($aryNoEmail as $aryIndividual) {
        $strBroadcastResults .= "<a href=\"/docs/edit_portfolio.php?model_id=$aryIndividual[Portfolio_ID]\" target=\"_blank\">$aryIndividual[Name]</a>&nbsp;,";
    }
}
return $strBroadcastResults;
}
```

Comment: Does anyone receive the emails, or is it just you who isn't getting them?

Comment: I never get one when i test it on 2 different of my emails.

Comment: Some of the models get the emails, some dont. Oddly, the only ones known to not be getting them are gmail accounts.

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder?

Comment: How can you claim successful sending without even checking the return value of `mail()`? That function returns false if there's an error handing off to the SMTP server.

Comment: How would I do that, just return mail(); ??

Comment: @RickBross - something like `$isSuccess = mail($to, $subject, $body)`, and then make sure that `$isSuccess` is true. I'd also check to see if your emails are going in the spam folders, too - if the same piece of code sends email to some domains successfully and others unsuccessfully, I'd say it was more likely an issue with the domains than with your code.

Comment: I did a if (mail(stripslashes($strRecipient), stripslashes($_REQUEST["frmBroadcastSubject"]),stripslashes( $_REQUEST["frmBroadcastBody"]), $strHeaders))

Comment: @RickBross - what about the other part of my suggestion?

Comment: I did have a few in my spam, in both emails. I wasnt getting these before, and im not getting them now. I guess i had found the solution earlier today but made too many changes already to find how i had the code before. :/ Im close, I can feel it.